# How do I fix these 5 Android SDK compilation errors?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I am following this viewflipper [tutorial](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/viewflipper). After the build I am receiving the following errors:

Unresolved reference: activity_main

Unresolved reference: view_flipper

Smart cast to 'ViewFlipper!' is impossible, because 'viewFlipper' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Smart cast to 'ViewFlipper!' is impossible, because 'viewFlipper' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Smart cast to 'ViewFlipper!' is impossible, because 'viewFlipper' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Listed below is the code to my MainActivity.kt
'''

```
 package com.example.mobilecop

 import android.R
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.view.Gravity
 import android.view.View
 import android.widget.TextView
 import android.widget.ViewFlipper
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var viewFlipper: ViewFlipper? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    viewFlipper = findViewById(R.id.view_flipper)
    val textView = TextView(this)
    textView.text = "Dynamically added TextView"
    textView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    viewFlipper.addView(textView)
    viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(2000)
    viewFlipper.startFlipping()
}

fun previousView(v: View?) {
    viewFlipper!!.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_right)
    viewFlipper!!.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left)
    viewFlipper!!.showPrevious()
}

fun nextView(v: View?) {
    viewFlipper!!.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left)
    viewFlipper!!.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_right)
    viewFlipper!!.showNext()
}
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

After removing import android. R, I was able to fix the first two errors.  I removed the following three lines and the app runs.

```
    '''viewFlipper.addView(textView)
       viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(2000)
       viewFlipper.startFlipping()
     '''
```